# Wifi card was working fine, now undetected by the system

Tags: wifi

My wifi has always worked, but I have been unable to connect for a couple of days, because the wireless interface can't be found.

I have a Thinkpad T470 with Intel Dual Band Wireless AC(2x2) 8265. On Debian testing, and firmware-linux-nonfree and firmware-iwlwifi are installed (not been updated for while).

lspci output does not show the network adapter

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM (rev 21)
```

`dmesg | grep iwl` is empty. `rfkill` only shows bluetooth. As the card is not detected at all, lsmod has no wireless modules loaded. On the other hand, bluetooth is fully functional and working.

I booted up using a debian-live-10.10.0-amd64-xfce+nonfree.iso on which everything should work, but again the wireless card was not detected.

So I did some more digging into the logs. On 9 Sep, my wifi was working fine, and was correctly loaded

```
Sep  9 13:26:50 jupiter kernel: [    5.791176] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
Sep  9 13:26:50 jupiter kernel: [    5.791529] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Sep  9 13:26:50 jupiter kernel: [    5.801795] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0xfed10000-0xfed15fff], which spans more than pnp 00:07 [mem 0xfed10000-0xfed13fff]
Sep  9 13:26:50 jupiter kernel: [    5.801804] caller snb_uncore_imc_init_box+0x78/0xc0 [intel_uncore] mapping multiple BARs
Sep  9 13:26:50 jupiter kernel: [    5.815752] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
Sep  9 13:26:50 jupiter kernel: [    5.816246] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.ad812ee0.0 8265-36.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
Sep  9 13:26:50 jupiter kernel: [    5.816877] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
```

Last error is harmless apparently.

I suspended the computer a couple of times till the next day (10 sep), when I resumed, and kern.log had the following errors and (selected) messages

```
: can't change power state from unknown to D0 (config space inaccessible)
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.686918] pcieport 0000:00:1c.6: can't change power state from D3hot to D0 (config space inaccessible)
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.703520] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: can't change power state from D3hot to D0 (config space inaccessible)
----------------
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.814434] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.814441] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.814808] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.814817] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.814826] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000040: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.814834] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000060: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.814842] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000080: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.814850] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 000000a0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.814858] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 000000c0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.814866] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 000000e0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.814874] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000100: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.814883] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000120: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.814891] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000140: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.814896] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.814968] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.814976] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.816693] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.6) config registers:
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.817206] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.817214] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.817223] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 00000040: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.817230] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 00000060: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.817238] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 00000080: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.817246] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 000000a0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.817254] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 000000c0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.817262] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 000000e0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.817270] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 00000100: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.817279] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 00000120: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.817287] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 00000140: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.817295] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 00000160: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.817303] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 00000180: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.817311] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 000001a0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.817319] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 000001c0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.817341] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 000001e0: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63338.817346] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.6: 00000200: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
----------
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63339.904678] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63339.904684] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63339.904685] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63339.904686] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -5
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63339.904687] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63339.961017] 
------------
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63339.961023] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 32706 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/../iwl-trans.h:1391 iwl_mvm_dump_lmac_error_log+0x4eb/0x540 [iwlmvm]
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63339.961023] Modules linked in: wacom hid_generic usbhid hid uinput acpi_call(OE) ctr ccm rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device bnep btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc jitterentropy_rng videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 drbg videobuf2_common videodev mc ansi_cprng ecdh_generic ecc nls_ascii nls_cp437 snd_hda_codec_hdmi vfat intel_rapl_msr snd_soc_skl intel_rapl_common fat snd_soc_hdac_hda intel_pmc_core_pltdrv snd_hda_codec_realtek intel_pmc_core snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_hda_intel intel_powerclamp snd_intel_dspcfg coretemp mei_hdcp mei_wdt soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation ghash_clmulni_intel snd_soc_core snd_compress aesni_intel iwlmvm soundwire_cadence libaes crypto_simd mac80211 snd_hda_codec cryptd glue_helper libarc4 snd_hda_core rapl
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63339.961050]  intel_cstate snd_hwdep soundwire_bus intel_uncore snd_pcm_oss joydev iwlwifi snd_mixer_oss efi_pstore serio_raw pcspkr snd_pcm iTCO_wdt intel_pmc_bxt iTCO_vendor_support wmi_bmof intel_wmi_thunderbolt watchdog snd_timer ee1004 cfg80211 mei_me ucsi_acpi intel_xhci_usb_role_switch sg typec_ucsi roles mei intel_pch_thermal typec thinkpad_acpi nvram ledtrig_audio snd soundcore tpm_crb ac evdev rfkill tpm_tis tpm_tis_core tpm rng_core acpi_pad parport_pc ppdev lp parport fuse configfs efivarfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic sd_mod t10_pi crc_t10dif crct10dif_generic uas usb_storage i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper crct10dif_pclmul crct10dif_common xhci_pci crc32_pclmul e1000e cec ahci crc32c_intel libahci psmouse xhci_hcd libata drm ptp scsi_mod pps_core i2c_i801 usbcore i2c_smbus usb_common wmi battery video button
--------------
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63339.961214] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: HW error, resetting before reading
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63339.996772] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63339.996774] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 3072
Sep 10 14:45:28 jupiter kernel: [63339.996775] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 36.ad812ee0.0 8265-36.ucode
-------------
Sep 10 14:45:30 jupiter kernel: [63344.915798] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
Sep 10 14:45:30 jupiter kernel: [63344.915814] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
Sep 10 14:45:30 jupiter kernel: [63344.915815] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
Sep 10 14:45:30 jupiter kernel: [63344.915816] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -5
Sep 10 14:45:30 jupiter kernel: [63344.915819] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
------------
Sep 10 14:45:34 jupiter kernel: [63348.625521] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
Sep 10 14:45:34 jupiter kernel: [63348.625564] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: can't change power state from D3hot to D0 (config space inaccessible)
Sep 10 14:45:34 jupiter kernel: [63348.625856] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?
Sep 10 14:45:34 jupiter kernel: [63348.635076] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:04:00.0 failed with error -5
```

After a restart iwlwifi does not appear again in kern.log

I would guess this is a hardware failure, but I would appreciate if someone has a way of reviving my card.

Comment: Was your restart attempt software-based or was it a full power-off and cold boot? It should be a cold boot. Have you tried removing the battery (and mains power), attempting to switch on (which will fail), and then reinserting the battery and powering on once more?

Comment: **After a restart iwlwifi does not appear again in kern.log** - this might indeed be the case.

Comment: Thanks @roaima. See my answer. I did what you said, and more. And it is now working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the mains power, opened up my laptop, removed both batteries, removed the wifi card completely. Then put it back in (and the batteries).

The wifi is now working again. I guess it just needed a super hard reset.

lspci

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

Comment: It probably was rather the re-seating of the module (which is a hard reset for the module's firmware) than the reset (unless the firmware completely stalled)... when the issue may still occur sporadically, it might still better to swap out the WiFi module.

Answer (score 1):

"Config space inaccessible" points to a hardware error: The PCIe config space contains the basic information about PCIe cards, for example where the hardware registers are located. If these has suddenly gone away, it means the WLAN hardware is not responding at all.

Similarly, if it doesn't show up in `lspci`, it means that the very basic hardware support that all PCI hardware implement has stopped working.

I'd second the procedure with removing both battery and mains power, because this will do a "real" cold boot, resetting the hardware as far as can be reset.

Another thing to look for is BIOS/UEFI settings, potentially you can enable/disable the WIFI hardware, and maybe it glitched to "disabled".

If both of these doesn't help, I'd assume the WIFI hardware is dead.

Comment: I removed external battery and power cable, disabled the internal one in BIOS, let it sit unpowered for while and then restarted. That did not help. I will open it up and actually disconnect the internal battery, and see if that helps.

My only question is, doesn't the same chip(Intel 8265) provide bluetooth capabilities? I am surprised that bluetooth is working, but wifi isn't.

Comment: We just had a similar question somewhere, and for my own Intel WIFI/BT chipset, it's the same: BT is provided via USB, while WIFI is provided via PCI. (Check with `lsusb`). So if only the PCI part of the WIFI hardware is damaged, the USB part is unaffected.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will accept yours as correct. I think chip has to be replaced. At least I have a thinkpad and it will be a breeze.

Comment: See my answer. It's working again. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This line here:

```
firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
```

... is a [know issue](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=966218) and one probably doesn't need that debug firmware.

```
nano /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

And then remove / comment out this line:

```
options iwlwifi enable_ini=N
```

I'd try to boot into livelinux and if it doesn't work there, just swap out the WiFi module. They're not expensive and ThinkPads are quite serviceable, therefore it's not difficult to replace such a module. While most ThinkPads also have a tiny hardware switch for the radios ...which can fully disable it.